# Python PyCharm - cannot install contextily

Tags: python, pip, networkx, geospatial, contextily

I am using **Python** with **PyCharm** and I am trying to run this code that I found [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/geospatial/plot_points.html):

```
from libpysal import weights, examples
from contextily import add_basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import geopandas

cases = geopandas.read_file("cholera_cases.gpkg")

coordinates = np.column_stack((cases.geometry.x, cases.geometry.y))

knn3 = weights.KNN.from_dataframe(cases, k=3)

dist = weights.DistanceBand.from_array(coordinates, threshold=50)

knn_graph = knn3.to_networkx()
dist_graph = dist.to_networkx()

positions = dict(zip(knn_graph.nodes, coordinates))

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
for i, facet in enumerate(ax):
    cases.plot(marker=".", color="orangered", ax=facet)
    add_basemap(facet)
    facet.set_title(("KNN-3", "50-meter Distance Band")[i])
    facet.axis("off")
nx.draw(knn_graph, positions, ax=ax[0], node_size=5, node_color="b")
nx.draw(dist_graph, positions, ax=ax[1], node_size=5, node_color="b")
plt.show()
```

The problem is that, after I installed the imported libraries, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...my.path...", line 14, in <module>
    from contextily import add_basemap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'contextily'
```

If I try to install the missing module (`pip install contextily`) I get:

```
...
Collecting rasterio
  Using cached rasterio-1.2.10.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More information is available in the README.
      ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I need your help: the answers from related questions did not work well. What can I do?

Comment: Which version of Python do you have? `rasterio` 1.2.10 is pretty old and doesn't have precompiled wheels for Windows.

Comment: @AKX I have 3.7

Comment: The error message looks clear.  You should be consulting the README to see how to supply a goal file.

Comment: Well, did you look at the readme?

Comment: Dear @duffymo & @DeepSpace, I can say I "looked" but honestly I don't understand what to do. Do you think this `https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/README.rst` says the answer?

Comment: @hellomynameisA Python 3.7 is also quite old and out-of-support these days.

Comment: I looked at the docs.  You should be following this: https://pypi.org/project/rasterio/

Comment: @duffymo Honestly, the message is not clear since the solution is "upgrade your Python to a currently supported version so `pip` can use a binary wheel instead of attempting to compile rasterio from scratch".

Comment: Almost there... GDAL went fine. Now I have: 
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rasterio-1.2.10-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rasterio-1.2.10-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64`

Comment: I am trying all versions to match the one that should work... `ERROR: rasterio-1.2.10-pp38-pypy38_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
`

Comment: @hellomynameisA Yes, a Pypy 3.8 wheel is not compatible with CPython 3.7. Please consider upgrading to a [currently supported Python version](https://endoflife.date/python).

Answer (score 0):

According to PyPi, Rasterio 1.3 works with Python 3.8+, Numpy 1.18+, and GDAL 3.1+. PyPi also lists the python versions that are currently supported by the latest version of rasterio (1.3.9) i.e. Python 3.8 - 3.11.

Try upgrading your python version to any of these supported versions. You may want to refer here https://pypi.org/project/rasterio/ for more information.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but it did not solve the problem.